# Find rank of the special block symmetric and persymmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

I meet a difficult problem recently. The problem is to find the rank of a special matrix:
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} S & P \\ P & JSJ\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{2m\times2m} ,$$ where $S$ is symmetrix matrix (actually is a [hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix)) and $P$ is [Persymmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix) and $J$ is [Exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix).

I want to find out whether the case $detA = 0$ exists. One possible solution is to decompose the $X$ into multiplication of some block matrix. But hwo to do it? Could anyone provide some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @loupblanc Oh, I am sorry that I forgot to deal with that problem. I was busy with some other things that time. That problem is a simplified one.

Comment: Since you didn't impose any restrictions on $P,S$ other than being symmetric or persymmetric, then you should consider the case where $P=0$ as well. So you'll easily end up with $$\text{rank }X\ge2\text{rank }S$$

Comment: @polfosol Yes, thanks for providing a useful case!